# Creating an image with rounded corners in a windows 8 metro application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to create an animated playing card in a windows 8 metro application.
I found that by using 2 rectangles in xaml and with a transform and setting the z order I can get a decent looking animation. However when I try and add a child image ( for the face of the card ) to one of the rectangles I can't compile.

Is there any way to use a xaml image tag inside of a rectangle so that you can use the radiusX radiusY properties to round the corner?

Heres what Im using that allows the rotation ( both x and z planes )

```
<Rectangle x:Name="cardRectBack"  Stroke="{StaticResource HyperlinkPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Tapped="cardRect_Tapped" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateCard"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle.Projection>
            <!-- Apply a PlaneProjection to the image -->
            <PlaneProjection x:Name="backYRot" RotationY="20"/>
        </Rectangle.Projection>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFBB4444" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ImageBrush` instead of `LinearGradientBrush`:

```
<Rectangle.Fill>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/MyImage.png" />
</Rectangle.Fill>
```